# How can the var(|X|) be defined?

Tags: variance, expected-value

I know that $var(|X|) = E[|X|^2] - (E[|X|])^2 = E[X^2] - (E[|X|])^2$.

However, I don’t know if (E[|X|])^2 can be simplified in terms of E[X] or something similar that has no absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \int_\mathbb{R} x f(x) dx\\
\mathbb{E}[|X|]
  &= \int_\mathbb{R} |x| f(x) dx
   = \int_0^\infty x f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 x f(x) dx\\
  &= \mathbb{E}[X] - 2\int_{-\infty}^0 x f(x) dx
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_+=\max(X,0)=X{\bf 1}_{\{X>0\}},~X_-=\max(-X,0)=-X{\bf 1}_{\{X<0\}}$.

Then  $X=X_+-X_-$, and $|X|=X_++X_-$. 
Also,  $X_+,X_-\ge 0$ and $X_+X_-=0$.

Using these,

$$\mbox{Var}(|X|) = \mbox{Var}(X)-4 E[X_+]E[X_-]=\mbox{Var}(X) + 4 E[X{\bf 1}_{\{X>0\}}]E[X{\bf 1}_{\{X<0\}}].$$

So Variance of $|X|$ is always less than or equal to variance of $X$ with equality if and only if $|X|=X$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Could you please explain the process of getting the equation Var(|X|) = Var(X) - 4*E[X^+]E[X^-] ?

Comment: 1. $E[|X|^2] = E[X^2]$; 2. 1. $X = X_+- X_-$ and $|X| = X_+ + X_-$; therefore 3. $E[|X|]^2 = E[X_+ + X_-]^2 = E[X_+-X_-]^2 + 4 E[X_+]E[X_-]$.